# Enabling Authentication for FitNesse Tests

Tags: java, authentication, fitnesse

I would like to enable authentication for our FitNesse tests. It is described on the [FitNesse documentation page](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.PasswordFile).

I tried that, but I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
java -cp fitnesse-standalone.jar fitnesse.authentication.Password -f  c:/temp/Fitnesse/FitnesseAuthentication.txt -c fitnesse.authentication.HashingCipher
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
        at fitnesse.authentication.Password.args(Password.java:59)
        at fitnesse.authentication.Password.main(Password.java:21)
Usage: java fitnesse.authentication.Password [-f <password file>] [-c <password cipher>] <user>
        -f <password file> {passwords.txt}
        -c <password cipher> {fitnesse.authentication.HashingCipher}
```

Does anyone know the correct way to create the Hashed version of the authentication file on a Windows platform?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Windows - I got the same message on a Linux system.

In the case somebody is looking for the same error (and also didn't read the usage hint) you have to specify a username after the cipher (-c argument), e.g.

```
java -cp fitnesse-standalone.jar fitnesse.authentication.Password -f  c:/temp/Fitnesse/FitnesseAuthentication.txt -c fitnesse.authentication.HashingCipher admin
```